# Guardar datos en la base de datos, mediante un fomulario en Django

Tags: python, django

quiesera guardar comentarios en la base de datos y no entidendo bien como realizarlo, espero que me puedan ayudar, el template me muestra de manera correcta. gracias.

MODELO:

```
  class Critica(models.Model):
        ESTADO_CHOICES = (
       ('rechazada', "Rechazada"),
        ('valida', "válida"),
                           )
       nombre=models.CharField(max_length=20)
       pelicula=models.ForeignKey(Pelicula, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
       criticas=models.CharField(max_length=300)
       aprobado=models.CharField(max_length=30,choices=ESTADO_CHOICES, default='valida')
       puntaje=models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(1),MaxValueValidator(5)])
      email=models.EmailField()

      def __str__(self):
               return '%s %s %s %s'%(self.nombre,self.pelicula,self.criticas,self.puntaje)

      def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
             super(Critica, self ).save(*args, **kwargs) 
             self.pelicula.get_promedio()
```

FORM.PY:

```
class criticaForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
          model= Critica
          fields= ['nombre','criticas', 'puntaje', 'email']
```

VIEW:(esta vista, muestra detalles de una pelicula y contiene el fomulario de criticas)
class PeliculasView(TemplateView):
template_name = 'PeliculasInfo.html'
form_class = criticaForm()

```
def get(self, request, pk):  # Implementa el metodo get, le pasas el pk como parametro que 
                              declaras en el path de tu url
    context = {
        'pelicula': Pelicula.objects.get(pk=pk),
        'Actores': Actores.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
        'Director': Director.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
        'criticas': Critica.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
        "titulo": "PeliculasWeb 2023 | Informacion",
        'form': self.form_class
    }            

    if request.method =='POST':
        form= form(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect(reverse('PeliculasView') + '?ok')  
        else: 
            return redirect(reverse('PeliculasView') + 'error')

    return render(request, self.template_name, context) # Returnas el método render que 
    mostrara el contenido del template y el diccionario de contexto.
```

URLS:
path("info/int:pk/", views.PeliculasView.as_view(), name="info"),

TEMPLATE:

```
<pre> 
  <div class="texto-pelicula">
      <h4>Comentarios:</h4>
         <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token%} <!-- codigo de seguridad para enviar el formulario-->
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </form>
   </div>
   <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Publicar" class="btn btn-primary">
   </div>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

si quieres grabar lo que han puesto en el formulario, no lo puedes hacer en "def get", lo tienes que hacer en "def post" y te quedaria asi.

```
def get(self, request, pk):  # Implementa el metodo get, le pasas el pk como parametro que 
                          declaras en el path de tu url
context = {
    'pelicula': Pelicula.objects.get(pk=pk),
    'Actores': Actores.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
    'Director': Director.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
    'criticas': Critica.objects.filter(pelicula=pk),
    "titulo": "PeliculasWeb 2023 | Informacion",
    'form': self.form_class
}

return render(request, self.template_name, context) # Returnas el método render que
mostrara el contenido del template y el diccionario de contexto.


def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    form= form(data=request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect(reverse('PeliculasView') + '?ok')  
    else: 
        return redirect(reverse('PeliculasView') + 'error')
```